# What is the possible Maximum Salt and Maximum password length

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am using AES (javax.crypto.Cipher) Two way encryption (Salt and Password) to encryption some strings which save in the database. Here comes my encryption properties are AES 128 Bit , Padding AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding , 1000 password iteration , 128 key size.

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
currentSpec = new PBEKeySpec("password", "salt".getBytes(),1000  , 128);
```

a. What is the maximum Salt size (Length of characters )?

b. What is the maximum Password size (Length of characters )?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [getMaxAllowedKeyLength](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)

Comment: you only show the code for generating the encryption key, the salt / password has nothing to do with the actual encryption and there is no maximum size for both

Comment: @man: there is the limit of 2^{31}-1 elements in _any_ Java array :-)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yea you got a point there